USB wifi connection gone after STEAM client installation
I am currently bootin into Win11 to write this, as Ubuntu has lost internet connection as I state in the title.
So I installed STEAM client, and after that the program started downloading and installing all the necessary steam updates and add ons. I started downloading Halo Infinte. Everything was fine when I powered off the PC. Next day the USB wifi connection device is not recognized anymore.
Where do I start to debug this? New to Ubuntu.

You've provided no Ubuntu product/release details which is the usual starting point (ie. are you using Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS? Ubuntu Desktop 24.10? etc) and how you installed the Steam client, as your details indicate that is related.  Problems due to package changes aren't always apparent until next reboot; so your issue appears to be related specifically to something you've done, but you're without specifics providing only a vague summary.  Please be specific with details for specific help.  Currently I'd suggest exploring your system logs to see what you changed!

eg. to view what deb package changes I made; I'd use view /var/log/apt/history.log on my system to view the logs; but you've not provided any clues as to what Ubuntu product/release you're using, so adjust for your unstated Ubuntu product/release.

The steam client was installed via snap. Afterwards system prompted me to install nvidia libraries (libnvidia-gl-535:i386). This was through deb I Believe. Not sure.

I run Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (64bit) on AMD Ryzen 5 8600 processor with nvidia GeForce rtx 4060.

How do you uninstall the nvidia libraries?
